# How to write a regex that pulls unordered list and paragraph preceding it

Tags: python, regex

I have a beautiful soup object, which I've converted to a string and I want to pull all instances of bulleted lists and the paragraph immediately preceding them. An example is the following string:

```
...
    <p><strong><strong> </strong></strong>It can be hard to admit that rebranding is necessary. Companies can often be attached to their brand, even if it is hurting their sales. Consider rebranding if:</p>
    <ul>
    <li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li>
    <li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li>
    <li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li>
    <li>Management change</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/', '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding');">19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</a></li>
    </ul>
...
```

I use the following regex:

```
re.findall('<p>.*</p>\n<ul>.*</ul>', string)
```

However, it's returning an empty list. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I deleted my first comment because I decided to go Google your problem.  I found https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs-and-their-positions.  I noted that there is an "r" before the regexp.  Maybe you just missed that?

Comment: The `.*` likely is gobbling up the opening `<` of the `</ul>`.  I'd try `[~<]*` instead.  Also there may be more white space than a single `\n`.  This is not the approach I'd take.  I think any approach like this would be fragile.  Your "string" looks like parsable XML so you might consider using XSLT to grab what you want.

Comment: Wait. You parse the HTML properly with BeautifulSoup, and then you *un*parse it and want to use regexes to get the data out? Use the BeautifulSoup object directly! Don't try to parse HTML with regexes.

Comment: ([Obligatory.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML!**

BeautifulSoup can do everything you want easily, elegantly and correctly:

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r"""
    <p><strong><strong> </strong></strong>It can be hard to admit that rebranding is necessary. Companies can often be attached to their brand, even if it is hurting their sales. Consider rebranding if:</p>
    <ul>
    <li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li>
    <li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li>
    <li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li>
    <li>Management change</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/', '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding');">19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</a></li>
    </ul>
""")
>>> bulleted_lists = soup.findAll('ul')
>>> uls_with_ps = [(ul.findPrevious('p'), ul) for ul in bulleted_lists]
```

To get a feel for what's going on:

```
>>> bulleted_lists
[<ul>
<li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li>
<li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li>
<li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li>
<li>Management change</li>
<li><a href="http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/', '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding');">19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</a></li>
</ul>]

>>> bulleted_lists[0].findPrevious('p')
<p><strong><strong> </strong></strong>It can be hard to admit that rebranding is necessary. Companies can often be attached to their brand, even if it is hurting their sales. Consider rebranding if:</p>
```

Comment: When I pull <ul> tags from a page, there's lots of <li> tags in them that I want to filter out that contain either attributes or children tags under them, such as the last <li> tag with href in the string I provided. I'm using text.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'ul' and not tag.attrs) to return <ul> tags. Is there a good way to modify that so that it also filters out any children <li> tags with attributes and with children under them. I just want to return <ul><li>string

Comment: That's a different question, for that you should open a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need `regex` while beautifulsoup is capable of handling any type of html completely- better you try [**css selectors**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here `div.Mother div.Son ul li` means select all `divs` with classname `Mother` then inside it select all `divs` with classname `Son` then select `ul` inside it and finally select all `li` inside `ul`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = """

    <body>
    <div class="Mother" >
        <div class="Son" >
            <p><strong><strong> </strong></strong>It can be hard to admit that rebranding is necessary. Companies can often be attached to their brand, even if it is hurting their sales. Consider rebranding if:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li>
                <li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li>
                <li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li>
                <li>Management change</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/', '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding');">19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

"""

soup = bs(data,'lxml')
#To grab all inside the ul
for item in soup.select('div.Mother div.Son'):
    print item.text.strip()
print  "="*100
#Just to grab all li    
for li in soup.select('div.Mother div.Son ul li'):
    print li.text.strip()
```

Output-

```
It can be hard to admit that rebranding is necessary. Companies can often be attached to their brand, even if it is hurting their sales. Consider rebranding if:

You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers
If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver
If you want to attract a new target audience
Management change
19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding
====================================================================================================
You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers
If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver
If you want to attract a new target audience
Management change
19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding
```